# Setup 2 domains inside active directory

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

I need to setup 2 domains inside my active directory..

By using the method in this tutorial: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755059%28WS.10%29.aspx

I can setup a domain but after that when I use dcpromo then i cannot add another domain to the active domain. How can I do that?

Comment: I just need these 2 domains inside active directory because I have another application that will read users from these domains inside active directory and you know it's easier to manage users from there.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve (forget about *how* you want to do it for now) please?  2 domains seems overkill for the requirements of just one other app, especially if all it does is read users.  What is the app?  Have you looked at Active Directory Application Mode?  Even if it turns out that you need a second AD, this might be more useful (and less messy longer term).

Comment: It's service like application that users can login to it and use it. The problem with it is that it can only have User Templates on active directory domains. I have 2 category of users Normal users and Demo Users so when i want to create user remotely I have to create usee in 2 different domains (1 for demo users and 1 for normal users so the program can apply it's differen template of privileges on those users)

Comment: It sounds like you just need a different OU then, or is the app not OU-aware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows will only allow one domain per server instance. To install another domain, you'll either need another physical box or you'll need to virtualize the second instance of Windows Server. Either way, you'll need a second license for your server software.

If money is tight, you could install VMware Server (free) on your existing Windows Server and install a second instance within a VM on the same physical hardware. This certainly is not a workable long-term solution, but for testing/development purposes, it should be just fine.

Regarding your reason for needing two domains, it's not immediately clear why you'd need two domains. Can you expound on that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really need is [ADAM](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/default.mspx) for 2003, but is now called [AD LDS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770639(WS.10).aspx)

Simplified, this technology allows you to run multiple AD services.  In your link you were trying to create a new forest.  If you need a seperate domain, you could install another DC in a new child domain (eg. current domain is mydomain.internal, the new domain would be demo.mydomain.internal) See this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731394(WS.10).aspx)